# Why no __getitem__ raises TypeError

Tags: python

So the question is pretty simple:
If we have a random class, let's say an int and we try to access a non defined attribute:

```
my_int = 5
my_int.this_is_a_test
```

We will get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'this_is_a_test'
```

But if we try to access an index of it (in which case Python will do a lookup for a `__getitem__` attribute):

```
my_int = 5
my_int[0]
```

We get:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

What is the logic behind the change in exception type? It seems weird to me that a `TypeError` is raised, complaining about a missing attribute (`AttributeError` seems like a much better candidate for that)

Comment: If you accessed `my_int.__getitem__` directly, you'd get an `AttributeError`. But *that's an implementation detail* - the problem you're seeing is that it doesn't support indexing, which is a type error.

Comment: Note that the first example references an attribute, while the second example references an item.

Comment: There's no abc `Indexable` (all kinds of containers use `__getitem__`), but I guess the `TypeError` is supposed to hint that `int` is not of any type that is indexable.

Comment: Although I would like it better if `my_int[0]` would raise an `AttributeError` that says there's no `__getitem__`. After all, square bracket notation is supposed to be syntactic sugar for calling `__getitem__`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That’s not a very good explanation, given Python’s tradition of “duck typing.” When `foo` is missing an expected `bar` attribute, that is a type error from a duck-typed point of view. I suspect that this is simply an accident of history and there’s no deep logic in it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, some really weird types might have a C-level `tp_getitem` without a Python-level `__getitem__`, or a Python-level `__getitem__` without a C-level `tp_getitem`. `tp_getitem` is what's used for indexing, so whether a type supports indexing is actually somewhat decoupled from whether it has `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your intention.

```
In [1]: my_int = 5

In [2]: my_int.__getitem__(0)  # -> AttributeError

In [3]: my_int[0]  # -> TypeError
```

When you use `.` you implicitly call the `getattr` function, that naturally raises the `AttributeError` if the attribute doesn't exist.

**Update 2**. Let's look at the bytecode.

```
In [11]: import dis

In [12]: def via_operator():
             my_int = 5
             my_int[0]


In [13]: def via_getattr():
             my_int = 5
             my_int.__getitem__(0)

In [14]: dis.dis(via_operator)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (my_int)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (my_int)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             13 POP_TOP             
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE        

In [15]: dis.dis(via_getattr)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (my_int)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (my_int)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__getitem__)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 POP_TOP             
             19 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you see, the `[]` has a special virtual-machine instruction. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html)

> BINARY_SUBSCR: Implements TOS = TOS1[TOS].

Hence it's quite natural to raise a `TypeError`, when you fail at executing an instruction.

**Update 1**: Looking at the `getattr` sources, it's clear that this function can never raise such a `TypeError`, hence the `[]` operator doesn't call it under the hood (for the built-in types at least, though it's better to find the sources to clarify this bit).

```
static PyObject *
builtin_getattr(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *v, *result, *dflt = NULL;
    PyObject *name;

    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "getattr", 2, 3, &v, &name, &dflt))
        return NULL;
#ifdef Py_USING_UNICODE
    if (PyUnicode_Check(name)) {
        name = _PyUnicode_AsDefaultEncodedString(name, NULL);
        if (name == NULL)
            return NULL;
    }
#endif

    if (!PyString_Check(name)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                        "getattr(): attribute name must be string");
        return NULL;
    }
    result = PyObject_GetAttr(v, name);
    if (result == NULL && dflt != NULL &&
        PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_AttributeError))
    {
        PyErr_Clear();
        Py_INCREF(dflt);
        result = dflt;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but square bracket notation is sugar for calling `__getitem__`, so the real question is if an `AttributeError` would not be more consistent when trying to implicitly call `__getitem__` and the method does not exist.

Comment: @timgeb I'm now scrolling through the source code to understand that.

Comment: @timgeb I guess, I've found a reasonable explanation.

Comment: Hey this is really interesting, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

An `AttributeError` for `my_int[0]` may be misleading because you aren't trying to access an *attribute* of `my_int`, you are trying to access an *item*. The `TypeError` is raised because `int` doesn't support subscripting, and this exception message was updated in Python 3.X.

That being said, it wouldn't be inappropriate to throw an `AttributeError` that there is no `__getitem__`. I suspect that this may be a `TypeError` because numbers (`int`, `float`, `long`) are the only built-in data-types that do not support subscripting.

When this error comes up, it will be due to you thinking that `my_int` contains an object of a different type, hence the `TypeError`.